# Delphi - Why is TDate and TDateTime the same?

Tags: delphi, tdatetime

when looking in System.pas there TDate und TDateTime defined as the following:

```
  TDateTime = type Double;

  TDate = type TDateTime;
  TTime = type TDateTime;
```

obviously TDate and TDateTime are the same.

I just struggled working with TDate and TDateTime bacause I expected that TDate only contains the date-part and not also the time-part.

Now I'm wondering: What the sense behind this? 
When I declare a variable as TDate, then It should contain a date, and not a dat and a time-value.

Answer (score 8):

They are not the same. If the declarations had been

```
TDate = TDateTime;
TTime = TDateTime;
```

they *had* been the same. With the additional `type`, although they are still technically the same, i.e., they are still `double`s, they can be told apart. This, for instance, makes it possible to use different property editors in the Object Inspector for the two types (a date picker and a time picker, respectively), while you may use a 'date-time' picker for `TDateTime`.

In addition, even if it weren't for this, it might be good to use different 'aliases' for different purposes. This might make your source code easier to understand. For instance, if you do

```
var
  StartTime: TDate;
```

then you know that `StartTime` contains only information about the date, and not the time (unless you abuse the norms).

Comment: In addition, you cannot use a TDateTime as an actual var parameter, when a TDate is declared.

Comment: Of course it'S good that TDate and TTime types exists, but when a TDate would contain a Date (and not date AND time) and a TTime would contain only a time-value - then code would be even more easy to understand, I think ;).  And when the programmer tries to "abuse the norms" the compiler should give an error or at least a warning.

Comment: That was not the question. Poster is wondering why a TDate type holds time information at all. Obviously, he does not want to have to crop off time information with a date=int(TDate) every single time he needs just a date, which I think is a very reasonable positon.

Comment: In that regard, the definition should have been:

TDate = type integer;